# Issue trying to hyperlink an image

Tags: php, html, css

```
<div id="left_column">
<p><a href="http://www.google.com"><img class="browse_iphone" src="../public/img/browse_iphone.jpg" width="250" alt= "iPhone Accessories" height="130"></a></p>
</div>
```

That's my code and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've spent the last hour googling different methods to no avail.

Comment: Your protocol is wrong. Should be `http://www.google.com`

Comment: Oops, that's what happens at 1am. Corrected it and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: plus 1 for spotting the missing Hypertext Transfer Protocol!

Comment: your link is still incorrect `http:www.google.com` isn't the same as `http://www.google.com`

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/86enybL4/

Comment: Thanks for the live demo Alex. I don't understand what could be causing it to not work on my website.

Comment: If the fiddle works, and yours doesnt, and the only thing thats different is the image url path........

Comment: My image is loading perfectly fine though minus the hyperlink..

Comment: through minus the hyperlink means.Try to right click on the image and then copy the image location. Check the image path if its right

Comment: `src="../public/` that will fail, which is the source of your problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried to change it to a more direct path and it wouldn't load the image at all anymore. The only way I can load it is using that path.

Please keep in mind that I'm using mamp as a test server!

Comment: If you're going to use a server system path, use `/public/img/...` without the `../` at the beginning like you have. Or use `../img/` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: But, you tagged this as `php`, why? Relevance?

Comment: Tried to remove the ',,' and it gave me a broken image.
Will try out the error reporting tomorrow morning.

I'm still learning and the block of code came from my .php file so I assumed I would tag php?

Comment: Ok, so you say the only way you can use that image is with that path. So, what's the question/problem? You didn't specify that. Remember to `@` me, otherwise I won't see it. The open tab I have for this may not be opened later.

Comment: I can use that image with that path perfectly fine. But when I hover over it and click it, it doesn't take me to google.com as the hyperlink should. So the hyperlink isn't work.

I don't know if this helps but when I right click the image, it's not detecting it as an image so it doesn't give me the normal options that you get when you right click an image.    @Fred-ii-